# Is there a way to have a central place for variables that can be used in Visual Studio projects, Xcode projects, and Makefiles?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, makefile, cross-platform

I'm working on a fork of a cross-platform C / C++ open-source project that can be compiled for macOS, Windows, and Linux. The project uses a different toolchain for compiling for each platform: Xcode, Visual Studio, and Makefiles respectively.

I'd like there to be a central location in the project for defining certain variables and their values that can be used when building on all three platforms. That is to say, the Xcode project, Visual Studio project, and Makefiles will all be able to use the values of these variables in their build settings.

Short of doing something like rewriting the entire build system to use cmake or something similar (which I am not inclined to do if it can be avoided), is there any trick I can use to do this?

Comment: You could use environment variables? Otherwise you'll probably need to make your own mini cmake which generates props files for visual studio, xcconfig files for xcode and mk files for make from a common source file

Comment: Using a build system or a solution generator (CMake, premake, ...) seems the cleaner way.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm inclined to agree, but unfortunately I've inherited a rather bizarre custom build system from this open source project that spits out Xcode and Visual Studio projects. It would take a lot of work to get it working with cmake, so I'm hoping for a halfway decent shortcut.

Comment: If the solutions are generated, you have to look at options of your *"bizarre custom build system"*...